# How to set a readonly property in a C# async constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I have a service in an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API. The constructor is async because it calls an async method. But because the constructor is async, it's complaining about trying to initialize a property.

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public async Task MyService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this._serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        await DoSomething();
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

**"A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)"**

Any ideas?

Comment: What you show is not a constructor but a method. As far as I remember there are no async constructors.

Comment: Hi Nkosi. Thanks for your reply. I have updated my post to make it more clear.

Comment: What you have there is an async method with the same name as its enclosing type

Comment: You cannot make async constructor. Constructors don't return values. You just created a method.

Comment: That code cannot be valid; constructors cannot return values and they cannot be async.

Comment: that's still not a constructor,  a constructor does not return anything as it simply creates an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. So I guess it's not possible to have an async constructor then. So is it possible to call and await an async method from inside a constructor?

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez Plus that wont compile because  `member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`

Comment: You might find [this article from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) instructive.

Comment: Add a `Lazy` field to your class; initialize your async bits in the initialization function you pass to the `Lazy`.

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez: No, you cannot have an async constructor. [There are a few other options, though](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. Busy reading the links from Mathew and Stephen now...

Comment: Consider the thread safety issues that would arise if you *could* have async constructors.

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez Seems Stephen and I both posted the same link. ;)

Comment: @rory.ap Noted. I'll remove my comment then.

Comment: Ok the links provided by Mathew and Stephen (which are the same link) provide a good solution. Nkosi I know you suggested I delete this post, but perhaps I should answer it, stating the given link as the answer, for future developers making the same mistake I made? I'm not sure what's the best approach / recommended practice here.

Comment: Ok just saw the updated comments now. I will proceed to answer the question...

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez I removed my previous comment based on feed back from other commenters. Add the self answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common example to solve your problem is to create a static method on the class and call the `async` method from there and well as the constructor.

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public static async Task<MyService> BuildMyService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        await DoSomething();
        return new MyService(serviceScopeFactory);
    }

    public MyService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this._serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As users mentioned in the comments above, I was mistaken to think that I could make a constructor async.

Mathew Watson and Stephen Cleary provided me with a link with a good alternative to my problem: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Summary:

**Factory Pattern**
Use a static creation method, making the type its own factory:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
  private MyData asyncData;
  private MyClass() { ... }

  private async Task<MyClass> InitializeAsync()
  {
    asyncData = await GetDataAsync();
    return this;
  }

  public static Task<MyClass> CreateAsync()
  {
    var ret = new MyClass();
    return ret.InitializeAsync();
  }
}

public static async Task UseMyClassAsync()
{
  MyClass instance = await MyClass.CreateAsync();
  ...
}
```